# Logstash/WildFly10: SSL broken for TCP input

Tags: java, ssl, logstash, wildfly, tls1.2

I already had a working setup, sending logs via `org.jboss.logmanager.ext.handlers.SocketHandler` to Logstash TCP input and securing the connection by means of a server certificate. Since today, something seems to have broken SSL. The handshake seems to go well, the connection gets closed by the Logstash server right after. Here're some excerpts of what `-Djavax.net.debug=all` gave me:

```
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2

*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2

%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]

Found trusted certificate:

*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA

*** ServerHelloDone

SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:

CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
Server Nonce:
Master Secret:

*** Finished
```

Up to this point, everything seems to go well. However, the outputs stops with the following statement, when **logstash.log** shows that the connection is already closed:

```
(LogManager Socket Re) 0050: Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:    TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

More exactly, Logstash provides the following message:

```
:message=>"An error occurred. Closing connection", :client=>"172.16.0.6:51876", :exception=>#<IOError: bad record MAC>
```

To make sure that the server certificate is actually ok and not expired, I created a new one with openssl and added it to a new Java truststore:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out logstash_key.pem 2048
$ openssl req -new -sha256 -key logstash_key.pem -out logstash.csr
$ openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -key logstash_key.pem -in logstash.csr -out logstash_cert.pem
$ keytool -import -file logstash_cert.pem -alias logstash -keystore logstashTruststore
```

Then, I added the newly created truststore as a JVM argument:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/path/to/logstashTruststore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="password"
```

The `SocketHandler` that's used for my purposes is configured as follows (WildFly10 **standalone.xml**):

```
<custom-handler name="LOGSTASH" class="org.jboss.logmanager.ext.handlers.SocketHandler" module="log.logmanager-ext">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="LOGSTASH-FORMATTER"/>
    </formatter>
    <properties>
        <property name="hostname" value="{logstash-host-IP}"/>
        <property name="port" value="12202"/>
        <property name="protocol" value="SSL_TCP"/>
    </properties>
</custom-handler>
```

And last but not least, this is how I setup Logstash TCP input:

```
input {
    tcp {
      port => 12202
      codec => "json"
      ssl_enable => true
      ssl_cert => "/path/to/logstash_cert.pem"
      ssl_key => "/path/to/logstash_key.pem"
      ssl_verify => false
   }
 }
```

A shot overview of which versions I'm running:

- WildFly 10
- Java 8 (on client and server side)
- Logstash 2.1.3
- logstash-input-tcp-3.0.2

Thx for help!

Comment: Big thanks for the detailed instructions. Did anything change in the stack? Like a Java version update or anything.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins On the server side, I didn't apply any updates. However, I can't tell this is also true for my local Windows machine, which updates automatically. I also thought of version-relates issues. However, I could verify that the behavior is still the same from different client machines at our company. You think signing the certificate with a custom root cert might be a solution?

Comment: @PatrickOutOfBounds could you check for if there is enough available entropy on your logstash server, also the wildfly one. A long shot but could be the issue.

Comment: @ctomc thanks for answering. This might be a dumb question but: How to do that?

Comment: @PatrickOutOfBounds something along the lines of 
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail 
if number less than 100-200 that might be an issue

Comment: @ctomc Thanks, I'll try that on the Logstash VM (which is on Ubuntu btw). The WilfFly is running on Windows 7. Is there also an approach for finding the entropy on Windows?

Comment: never mind than, windows always has enough entropy.

Comment: @ctomc cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail gives me 842. I'm running kernel version 3.13.0-93-generic.